# BufferedReader pointer

Tags: java, file, input, bufferedreader

I have the following code but I don't understand how I can reset the pointer to the starter position:

```
BufferedReader inp=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
Scanner leggi=new Scanner(inp);
for(int i=0;i<nwords;i++){
  while(leggi.hasNext()) 
    if(leggi.next().equals(args[i+2])) 
      occorrenze[i]=occorrenze[i]+1;
}
inp.close();
```

I tried

```
inp.mark(0);
inp.reset();
```

with no results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java BufferedReader back to the top of a text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262618/java-bufferedreader-back-to-the-top-of-a-text-file)

Comment: Please see my revised Answer below. I added some code to my Answer, but SOF doesn't notify you of edits, but does notify you of new comments; hence this comment ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul,

I suggest you read through this old thread: [Java BufferedReader back to the top of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/262618/69224).

Personally I prefer Jon Skeet's response, which boils down to "Don't bother [unless you MUST]."

Cheers. Keith.

---

**EDIT:** Also you should ALLWAYS close that input file, even if you hit an Exception. The `finally` block is perfect for this.

---

**EDIT2:**

Hope you're still with us.

Here's my attempt, and FWIW, you DON'T need to reset the input-file, you just need to transpose your `while` and `for` loops.

```
package forums;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WordOccurrenceCount
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      String[] words = { "and", "is", "a", "the", "of", "as" };
      int[] occurrences = readOccurrences("C:/tmp/prose.txt", words);
      for ( int i=0; i<words.length; i++ ) {
        System.out.println(words[i] + " " + occurrences[i]);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static final int[] readOccurrences(String filename, String... words) 
    throws IOException
  {
    int[] occurrences = new int[words.length];
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
      reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
      while ( scanner.hasNext() ) {
        String word = scanner.next();
        for ( int i=0; i<words.length; i++ ) {
          if ( words[i].equals(word) ) {
            occurrences[i]++;
          }
        }
      }
    } finally {
      if(reader!=null) reader.close();
    }
    return occurrences;
  }
}
```

And **BTW**, **java.util.Map** is perfect for building a frequency table... [Parallel arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array) are just SOOOOO 90's. The "default" implementation of Map is the `HashMap` class... By default I mean use HashMap whenever you need a Map, unless you've got a good reason to use something else, which won't be often. HashMap is generally the best allround performer.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<nwords;i++){
BufferedReader inp=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
Scanner leggi=new Scanner(inp);
while(leggi.hasNext())if(leggi.next().equals(args[i+2])) occorrenze[i]=occorrenze[i]+1;

inp.close();
}
Like This???

Comment: Paul, no sorry, you've still got the same problem... Please see my edits above. As a general rule, performance dictates that we not re-read a file any more than necessarym, even if it is small enough to sit in the cache. Another general rule when dealing with loops-within-loops is "do the smaller part inside". Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- reset the FileReader (`FieldReader.reset`) instead and create a new bufferedreader.
- use mark functionaliy (try `BufferedReader.markSupported`)

I think what you tried is to call mark after you read the input. Instead do the following:

```
inp.mark(readAheadLimit);    
// .... all your code processing input
inp.reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

[`mark(int readAheadLimit)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#mark%28int%29) takes a `readAheadLimit` parameter.

You should not set the `readAheadLimit` to 0. Try using a meaningful number that is larger than number of bytes you read in an iteration.