# stop looping if method read next line empty

Tags: java

i do not know if the title is correct.
what i want to ask is how to stop looping if next line from method is empty.
i have 2 method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    rrr thisObj = new rrr();
    String command = br.readLine();
      while ((command = br.readLine())!=null) {
         int b=0;
         thisObj.perintah(b,command);
      }
}  

public void perintah(Integer indek, String PesanSumber)
   {
       String Pesan = PesanSumber.trim();
       int panjang = Pesan.length();
       if (panjang >=3)
       {
           if (Pesan.toLowerCase().trim().substring(0, 3).equals("log") )
            {
              System.out.println("bla bla bla");
            }
           else if (Pesan.toLowerCase().trim().substring(0, 4).equals("move"))
            { 
              System.out.println("bla bla bla");
            }
           else if (Pesan.toLowerCase().trim().substring(0, 4).equals("move"))
            { 
              System.out.println("bla bla bla");
            }
       }
    }
```

the problem is if i run it's not stop even next line is empty.

Comment: The method called `isEmpty()`.

Comment: @zakinster if he wants to stop on the first empty line (before EOF) he will need to add `&& !command.isEmpty()` or possibly `&& !command.trim().isEmpty()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 String command = br.readLine();
 while ((command = br.readLine())!=null) {
```

First, you're missing the first line by calling `readLine()` before the loop.
Secondly, you can add a second condition to check if the line is empty when it's not null :

```
 String command;
 while ((command = br.readLine())!=null && !command.isEmpty()) {
```

Now, it should stops where a line is empty or where there is no new line in the stream.

Comment: From [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29): `BufferedReader.readLine()` return null when EOF is reached. He/she will get a NPE in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to initialize the string twice, reading an empty line, so just change

```
String command = br.readLine();
```

to

```
String command;
```

Comment: I didn't even noticed ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can try following. Now it will stop.

```
 String command;
  while ((command = br.readLine())!=null) {
     int b=0;
     thisObj.perintah(b,command);
  }
```

In your code

```
  String command = br.readLine(); // you read empty line
  while ((command = br.readLine())!=null) { // But command will override by next line
     int b=0;
     thisObj.perintah(b,command);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With a Scanner, you can also use .hasNext() .next() methods which is quite a classical way of doing things. Example here : [BufferedReader pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841172/bufferedreader-pointer)

Answer (score 0):

I was just going through your code,
 `String command = br.readLine();` 
should be replaced with
 `String command = "";`
otherwise your first input will be missed.
And to answer your question, System.in does not returns null, so you must check for empty string as
 `String command;// br.readLine();
    while (!(command = br.readLine()).isEmpty())
    {
             int b = 0;
        thisObj.perintah(b, command);
    }`

This should work fine.

Comment: not good,my indek still zero after if im input move for time.

Comment: catatLog.put(indek,Nilai); i have that code in move condition

Comment: I am not clear about what you asking, can you please explain?