# change looping condition while with for on java

Tags: java

im novice in java,i have condition with while and it work nice but i need using looping with for:this while condition for looping

```
String command = "";
while ((command = br.readLine())!=null && !command.isEmpty()) {
  int b=0; 
  thisObj.perintah(b,command);
}
```

i have try write with for,i think similar like this but its not work

```
for (int b=0;b<command;b++)
   {
   String command = br.readLine();
   thisObj.perintah(b,command);
   }
```

did anyone know what i missing

Comment: What do you think that an inequality comparison between an integer and a string should do?

Comment: You are comparing the String command to the int b. That is not a good idea.

Comment: What's the point of `b` in your first snippet?

Comment: What you're asking is really **unclear**. `command` doesn't seem to be a number (given [your other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272122/stop-looping-if-method-read-next-line-empty)) and there is no way for us to guess what the purpose of `b` is and thus what value should it take.

Comment: In your `for` loop, the symbol `command` is not defined until you enter the loop body. You cannot use it in the `for` statement itself. Even if you could, the `<` operator is not defined between an `int` and a `String` value in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The while loop expressed as a for loop:

```
int b = 0;
for (String command = br.readLine(); command !=null && !command.isEmpty(); command = br.readLine()) {
  thisObj.perintah(b++, command);
}
```

---

Using the variable name `command` makes the `for` line quite long, so here's the same code with a shorter variable name so it's clearer what's going on:

```
int b = 0;
for (String s = br.readLine(); s !=null && !s.isEmpty(); s = br.readLine()) {
  thisObj.perintah(b++, s);
}
```

Comment: This is a `for each` loop.. It is definitely more appropriate but perhaps you can include a classic `for` loop too? Cover all the bases!

Comment: @Chris this is not a foreach: There is no iterable object here, nor is there the `:` operator of the foreach syntax. This is a standard `for` loop.

Comment: Merlin's beard. So it is. I retract my statement and award you a +1 for a lovely solution.

Comment: i need an increment because im using b for other method,your code just give 1 output for my other method

Comment: But your while loop doesn't increment `b`, and that was supposed to be the prototype for the for loop. Oh well, I've incremented b...

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what value should `b` take. Either way, you'll have to convert the string into integer though.

```
String command = "";
for(int b  = 0; (command = br.readLine())!=null && !command.isEmpty(); ++b) {
    thisObj.perintah(b,command);
    String command = br.readLine();
}
```

Comment: I believe you need an increment of `b` for this to compile?

Comment: yes i need increment b to using with my method

Comment: @poundPound but what's the relation between `b` and `command` ? Is this what you want ?

Comment: im use b for other method so that method will increment until command is null

Comment: @poundPound OK, I'm not sure whether I got it or not, but see my last edit.

Answer (score 0):

Java can't compare `int` with `String` without some help. You will need to convert the command into a number. Try `Integer.parseInt()`.

But you can't do that in the condition of the `for` loop. Try this instead:

```
int b = 0;
String command = "";
while ((command = br.readLine())!=null && !command.isEmpty()) {
  int commandAsInt = Integer.parseInt(command);
  if(b >= commandAsInt) break; // exit the loop

  thisObj.perintah(b,command);
  b++;
}
```

Comment: Why check if the line isn't = null and it isn't empty? One condition would do.

Comment: @Troubleshoot: I kept as much of the original code as possible.

Comment: @Troubleshoot see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272122/stop-looping-if-method-read-next-line-empty

Comment: How can the line be empty without being null?

Comment: @Troubleshoot A line with only a `\n` will return an empty `String` object which is not `null`.

Comment: thanks Aaron Digulla but it give error

Comment: Then fix that error or tell us exactly what the error is so we might be able to help.