# Java BufferedReader , resetting the reader

Tags: java

I have a particular method where I want to count the number of lines in a text file and then read the file 
what I am doing is counting the number of lines in the file by iterating over the read.nextLine() and then resetting the buffer and reading from the start of the file again. I am not sure what I am doing wrong

```
public void ReadFile() throws IOException{
 try{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(fr);
    int numberOfLines=0;
    while(read.readLine()!= null)
    {
        numberOfLines++;  // Getting the number of lines


    }

    read.reset();
    System.out.println(numberOfLines + ": is the no of lines");
    baseString.append(read.readLine());
    baseString.append(read.readLine());
    baseString.append(read.readLine());
    System.out.println(baseString);
 }
 catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

base string is just a Stringbuffer

```
private StringBuffer baseString = new StringBuffer();
```

I explicitly need the count to perform some operation

Comment: what is the problem exactly ?   and what is baseString ? where it is declared ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to first get the number of lines and then read the file? Can you not count the number of lines while reading it?

Comment: You need to mark the stream.

Comment: @MarounMaroun it wouldn't be really performing marking the beginning though.

Comment: You should find a way to process the file in one pass. This is just wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262618/java-bufferedreader-back-to-the-top-of-a-text-file) the **file** is read sequentially by `BufferedReader`, so you can't go back to the beginning of file with `reset` of BufferedReader

You have to create new `FileReader` and `BufferedReader`

OR

use [RandomAccessFile](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `mark()` on the stream. `Reader.reset()` isn't guaranteed to work if the stream hasn't been previously marked. The `BufferedReader` implementation of `reset()` in particular is only documented as returning to the previous mark.

Comment: that would not work..take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262618/java-bufferedreader-back-to-the-top-of-a-text-file)