# is there any way to reset a previously initialised `bufferedReader` to the beginnig of the stream?

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

What i want to do is, when I used an initialised `bufferedReader` which i used to read the lines from a file using `readLine()`, when I reach the end of file i want to use the same `bufferedReader` object to read lines from the beginnig of the same file for an example.

what i attempted to achieve this matter is, I used `mark()` and `reset()`, after initialising the `bufferedReader` I set `bufferReaderobject.mark(0)` and I  read the entire file and after that I used `bufferReaderobject.reset()` and agian read the entire file but then an exception was thrown. it seems that `reset()` only valid when the end of file has not reached.

is there any way to reset a previously initialised `bufferedReader` to the beginnig of the stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use `reset()` in such a way, the whole file must fit into the buffer of the `BufferedReader`.

That means you must either create a `BufferedReader` with a buffer that is large enough or create a new instance when you want to read the file again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
FileInputStream fIn = ...;
BufferedReader bRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));

// "reset" to beginning of file (discard old buffered reader)
fIn.getChannel().position(0);
bRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of BufferedReader for [mark method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#mark%28int%29) calls the parameter `readAheadLimit` and states that

> An attempt to reset the stream after reading characters up to this limit or beyond may fail.

So it seems that mark only works forward and doesn't works for reset to the start.

Also take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262618/java-bufferedreader-back-to-the-top-of-a-text-file).