# How to load an N_by_M matrix in Java with data fetched from a file without knowing dimensions?

Tags: java, file, multidimensional-array

There is a text file filled with 1's and 0's. I am trying to load one N_by_M matrix in Java with all data taken from that file. I do not know the dimensions of the matrix ahead of time because it depends on how much data the file has. What is guaranteed is that each line in the file contains the same number of characters.
My code snippet works, but I feel awkward about it because:

1. I am using a BufferedReader instance once only to calculate the number of rows and closing it and creating another instance only because I do not know how to rewind!
2. I am using the second instance to read the actual data and load to the matrix.
3. Within a loop, I am finding the column size. I need to find it only once. Yet, it is in a loop, finding it again and again which is redundant.

Please tell me how I could improve it by using BufferedReader only once and how to find the column only once.

```
    char[][] areas;
    String path = "C:\\test\\data.txt";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    String s;
    int numRows=0, numColumns=0;
    while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(numColumns==0)
            numColumns=s.length();
        numRows++;
    }
    br.close();
    areas = new char[numRows][];
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    int i=0;
    while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        areas[i] = s.toCharArray();
        i++;
    }
    br.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jon Skeet points out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262618/java-bufferedreader-back-to-the-top-of-a-text-file), I would not really bother if I had to multipass the file.

If you really want to pass it only once, I would consider reading line by line, storing each of them into a List, and process the list afterwards.

```
...
LinkedList<String> lines = new LinkedList<String>();
int numRows = 0, numCol = 0;
while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
  numRows++;

  // Filling list
  lines.addLast(s);
}

int[][] mat = new int[numRows][];

for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
  mat[i] = lines.get(i).toCharArray();
}

lines.clear();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have taken this out of the while-loop:   
if(numCol == -1)
    numCol = s.length();

Once the matrix is constructed, I can simply do this:
numCol = areas[0].length;

Answer (score 2):

I **strongly** suggest you start with `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path));` Since you then want to read all of the lines as `char[]`s, you could do something like

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path));
char[][] areas = new char[lines.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) {
    areas[i] = lines.get(i).toCharArray();
}
lines.clear(); // <-- since we wanted areas...
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not want to stop using BufferedReader.

Answer (score 0):

Rewind a BufferedReader:

```
br.mark();
// read some lines
br.reset();
```

Comment: Not possible for me to use. I do not know what limit to put on the mark since I do not have any knowledge of the amount of data, and number or rows and columns in the file.

Comment: Why not using the file size? Anyway, using a self growing List, as others pointed out, is IMO the best approach.