# use bufferedreader on a txt file twice?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

i have to count the lines on a file but later in the code I also have to print what's in that file, but I can't use the reader twice it just says null. How can I work this out without creating a bunch of bufferedreader objects?
thanks

Comment: just close the stream and create a new object, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421653/reset-buffer-with-bufferedreader-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262618/java-bufferedreader-back-to-the-top-of-a-text-file

Comment: count the number of lines you print instead.?

Comment: When you say 'later in the code' do you mean in the same method?
You can always have a counter for the number of lines and print the lines.

Answer (score 0):

1. Print and count at the same time?
2. Move the lines to an array then print them?
3. Make sure you've closed the file before reopening again?

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the buffer, and then re-opening it again.

```
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/main/java/com/william/sandbox/stackoverflow/samples20160306/Demo.java"));
    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    int lineCount = 0;
    while(line != null){
        lineCount += 1;
        line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Line count is: " + lineCount);

    bufferedReader.close();
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/main/java/com/william/sandbox/stackoverflow/samples20160306/Demo.java"));

    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    while(line != null){
        System.out.println(line);
        line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `BufferedReader`'s `mark()` and `reset()` methods to jump back to a specific position.

```
try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somefile.txt"))) {
    // marks this position for the next 10 characters read
    // after that the mark is lost
    r.mark(10);

    // do some reading

    // jump back to the mark
    r.reset();
}
```

Note that, `BufferedReader` supports marking but not all `Reader`s do. You can use `markSupported()` to check.